# T-SQL where clause field1 <> field2: they are datetime and field2 has NULLS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

WHERE FIELD1 <> FIELD2

FIELD1 and FIELD2 are datetime.  Sometimes either one of them has nulls, although rarely if ever do both have nulls.

However, this approach to coding it seems to completely EXCLUDE ALL RECORDS WHERE ONE IS NULL.

I didn't expect this. Set Ansi Nulls on or off makes no difference- so don't start there. :)

Any other explanation?  Of course, an Isnull(field,'some date') solves it- but what's the explanation for the other?
I get that Something + Null is Null, and many similar yucky behaviors of Null. But that doesn't help me understand why the statement as a whole would evaluate to TRUE ?

Comment: Try `isnull(field,'')`

Comment: But it is not evaluated to true.  EXCLUDE ALL RECORDS WHERE ONE IS NULL - means it evaluated to false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NULL comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489293/null-comparison)

Answer (score 1):

[Three valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).  `1 <> NULL` isn't true.  It isn't false, either.  It's **unknown**, the third truth value.  The WHERE clause returns a record when it evaluates to true, and unknown isn't true.  That's why it's best practice to *always handle your nulls*.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204037.aspx)'s the specific doc for SQL Server's T-SQL.

You want:

```
WHERE (FIELD1 <> FIELD2
    OR (FIELD1 IS NULL AND FIELD2 IS NOT NULL)
    OR (FIELD2 IS NOT NULL AND FIELD2 IS NULL))
```

Additionally, some RDBMSs may support this:

```
WHERE FIELD1 IS DISTINCT FROM FIELD2
```

SQL Server is not one of those RDBMSs, but IIRC, Sybase (the other dialect of T-SQL) *is*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336(v=sql.110).aspx) combined with [intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055(v=sql.110).aspx) or [except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055(v=sql.110).aspx)? Here's a self-contained example:

```
-- Filter for rows where ColA is the same as ColB
select Example.*
from (values
    (N'A', null)
  , (N'B', N'B')
  , (null, N'C')
  , (null, null)
) as Example (ColA, ColB)
where exists (
          select Example.ColA
          intersect
          select Example.ColB
      );

-- Filter for rows where ColA is not the same as ColB
select Example.*
from (values
    (N'A', null)
  , (N'B', N'B')
  , (null, N'C')
  , (null, null)
) as Example (ColA, ColB)
where exists (
          select Example.ColA
          except
          select Example.ColB
      );
```

Comment: Kittoes - thanks - not sure I need to go that complex,I knew it was a matter of handling nulls, just hoping for a *direct explanation of why - I guess the answer is, there's none - just always handle them - which I will remember from now on.

Comment: @Isaac What do you mean complex? This is as straightforward as it gets when you're comparing `X` to `NULL`. Any other method requires the use of branching logic via `OR` which will absolutely kill performance on any decent sized set.

Comment: @Issac Maintainability is also quite important and the `OR` version requires one to write 3 comparisons per column pair compared with 1 for the idiomatic `INTERSECT` or `EXCEPT` versions.

Answer (score 0):

The "direct answer of why" is *3-value logic*.  In short, NULL never equals anything, not True, not False, not NULL.  It's also never *not* equal to anything.  So, both,

```
X = NULL
X <> NULL
```

are false.

Many people speak of *a NULL value*, but that's a misnomer.  NULL denotes *missing* information: it's a lack of value.  The right way to think of it is as a marker *about* the value.  You can't compare something to nothing, or nothing to nothing, and the same goes for NULL.

The reason it seems weird is that no other commonly used programming language provides for missing information, and they use familiar Boolean (2-valued) logic.  SQL has the concept of "this is where a value would go, if value we had".  You don't bump into that idea many other places.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the NULL values to a low or high date value, something that neither field would be set to using ISNULL function

```
ISNULL(Field1, '1/1/1900') <> ISNULL(Field2, '1/1/1900')
```

Comment: thanks guys.  that's pretty much what I knew - and I've heard the oft-quoted, "null isn't anything, it's unknown".  I still sometimes wonder if microsoft and all the rest of us couldn't just be a little bit practical here. Is ONE the same as UNKNOWN?  well, no, it isn't.  one is UNKNOWN and one is ONE.  Yeah I get that UNKNOWN 'could' be ONE, the all we known for sure is ONE is ONE and UNKNOWN is UNKNOWN.  to me calling those 2 things "not the same" would be a reasonable conclusion to the almost ridiculous dogmatism we've been a bit too proud of for the last 20 years.. but thanks- I do get it